# Get the PID of the child process created through plink

Tags: c#, .net, putty, plink

I have a requirement where I have a windows server and a Linux host machine.

I spawn a new process in Linux host (`dotnet`) using plink form the windows server.

Now I want to know the PID of the child process created in Linux host sitting at windows server.

I can't figure out a way to do this. I'm using the following code to create a new process:

```cs
ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    Arguments = $" -pw {password} {username}@{resource} nohup /usr2/{username}/run.sh "
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardError = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = false,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PlinkExecutablePath"]
};

var p = Process.Start(pInfo);
```

Comment: Make your script print the PID? + In any case, do not run an external process (`plink`) to implement SSH. Use a native .NET SSH library, like SSH.NET.

Comment: It's fairly common in Linux land for an app to write out the PID to a file that can be read by other apps.

Comment: @davidG what if i dont want to use any file ... is there any other way

Comment: I see no reason why writing it to a file would be a problem.